# How to select the sheet with strings in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I did the code, but struck with a small function, how to set the specific worksheets depends on the string...

Example :

> if string = 23
>
> select (sheet2)
>
> if string = 34
>
> select (sheet3)
>
> if string =67
>
> select (sheet5).

I get the input from another workbook, and compare it with another workbook which has 6 sheet, each sheet has been differentiate by 2 integers in a row.

Example :
Workbook2

> sheet1 "A1:A100" have all the "23"
>   sheet2 "A1:A100" have all the "34"

I like to write a function,

```
Function sheetname(strcmp_1 As String)


If (strcmp_1 = "25") Then

sheetname = marco_2

End If

End Function
```

Comment: You question is a bit unclear :  
Given a string input, do you want to allocate it a worksheet using if statements?
What means, in the second example,  
> sheet1 "A1:A100" have all the "23" ?

Comment: I have coded that I can search the string in workbook1,example have "23". I want to select and the  active sheet example in this case "23" which is in workbook2,sheet1

Comment: so you just want to select a sheet dependig of a number in a function ? what is your exact Problem ? Worksheets(sheetname).Activate ?

Comment: I am interested to make a function, I dont know how to call the sheet name in my program

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need something like

```
Public Function SelectSheetByString(ByVal str As String, ByRef wb As Workbook) As Worksheet

With wb
    Select Case str
        Case "12"
            Set SelectSheetByString = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Case "34"
            Set SelectSheetByString = .Sheets("Sheet2")
        Case "56"
            Set SelectSheetByString = .Sheets("Sheet3")
    End Select
End With

End Function
```

I've added workbook as an argument due to your mentioning of "another workbook".
If you work inside one workbook call it with `wb:=ActiveWorkbook`.